# Eliminating/Altering a loop to speed up code

Tags: vba, excel, loops, do-loops, coding-efficiency

I have some VBA code written that runs quite slowly. I have a series of different loops in my code. I know that loops aren't always the most efficient way to manipulate data, so I think they are the problem. I need ideas for how to either alter the loop or eliminate it so I can speed up the run time of my code.

Below is the most active loop I have created. It's running through all of the cells on row D (starting in D2) and manipulating their values based off of entries in the cells in row 1. If I can get help on this loop I'll probably be able to use similar techniques to alter the other loops in my code. Any tips are appreciated.

```
'sub work week for date range
     Range("D2").Select
     Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
         If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)) = False Then
             ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value & "-" & Right(ActiveCell.Value, 4)
         Else: ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "-" & Right(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1), 4)
         End If
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Loop
```

Comment: Use arrays and loop through those.

Comment: As @Scott said - rather than referring to cells, pull those values into an array and loop through those.    _It's running through all of the cells on row D_ - does it really need to loop through 16384 cells (or 256 if on Excel 2003)?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest, and more efficient method, would be as has been suggested in the comments by using arrays.

To get you to that point though, I've given you the first steps to improving your interaction with VBA and understanding how to write your code without selecting or activating objects:

```
For i = 4 To Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    With Cells(2, i)
        If .Offset(-1, 0).Value = vbNullString Then
            .Value = .Value & "-" & Right$(.Offset(0, -1).Value, 4)
        Else
            .Value = .Offset(-1, 0).Value & "-" & Right$(.Value, 4)
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Basically, you don't need to `.Select` or `.Activate` anything. Work with the objects directly and use a variable to dictate the column rather than activating the next cell.

Once you're comfortable with writing code in this style, look at assigning a range's value to a 2D array and then loop through the array instead.

Answer (score 0):

For fast execution, my first recommendation is to turn automatic calculation and screen-updating off too if it still takes long.

I agree that anything that involves selecting is going to be incredibly slow so you should use range objects instead.

Final code:

```
' Declarations
Dim CurrentCell, LeftCell, PreviousCell As Range
Dim Last4Chars As String

'Initialize
Set CurrentCell = ActiveSheet.Range("D2")

'Optimizations
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop until Current Cell in Empty
Do Until IsEmpty(CurrentCell.Value)
    Set AboveCell = CurrentCell.Offset(-1, 0)        'One row above
    Set LeftCell = CurrentCell.Offset(0, -1)         'One column left

    If IsEmpty(AboveCell) = False Then
        CurrentCell.Value = AboveCell.Value & "-" & Right(CurrentCell.Value, 4)
    Else
        CurrentCell.Value = CurrentCell.Value & "-" & Right(LeftCell, 4)
    End If

    Set CurrentCell = CurrentCell.Offset(0, 1)
Loop

'Optimizations reversed for normal use
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```